# jMeter - Extract Value from Variable

Tags: jmeter

I am using jMeter to perform a stress test of a website. I need to pass a variable's value to the next Request.

The value can be seen as follows in the response body:

```
var _data = {};
_data["_as_csrf_token"] = "64da5d341c253c2a181796d2524e57c6502d906b";
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ data: _data, type: "POST" });
```

How should I use the Regular Expression Extractor to get this value?

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK - Excellent, the boundary made the trick!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use boundary extractor:

Set left to:

> data["_as_csrf_token"] = "

And right to:

> ";

If you want to use regex extractor then use:

> data\["_as_csrf_token"\] = "[^"]+?";

Answer (score 1):

The relevant regular expression would be:

```
_data\["_as_csrf_token"\] = "(\w+)";
```

Demo:

[image]

- you need to escape [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) first
- `\w` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for word characters (alphanumeric, case insensitive)
- `+` is the repitition

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, than you very much for the input. The boundary extractor worked perfect. However, very interesting your comments on RegEx usage.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following string to extract the data using ReEx Extractor.

```
_data\[\"_as_csrf_token\"\] \= \"(.+?)\"\;
```

As shown in the screenshot below
[image: Regular Expression Extractor Example]
In case you are worried about the data to be extracted. I would suggest using https://regexr.com/ The reason why i prefer this site is because it helps you with the cheatsheet as well.

Second question, why (.+?) why not anything else?
The reason is that it matches every kind of text within the pattern. No need to worry about the special characters.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, than you very much for the input. The boundary extractor worked perfect.